# Sending emails to multiple recipients using Wordpress contact form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, thunderbird, ovh, mass-emails

I've questions about create a contact form and sending one mail to multiple recipients.

I am a volunteer in an association and we need to regularly share a mailing list between more than 20 coordinators.
The main problem is that we need to update this list in a regular basis.

Another problem is that you can't send a single mail to more than 100 recipients using mozilla thunderbird (so we reach the mail recipients limit).

I search for a solution to easily have access to this list for each of coordinators.

We have a website so I thought I used it in a clever way to share the said mailing list between coordinators and also be able to update it (add or delete contacts).

I tried those steps:

I created a wordpress page protected by a password, with a simple contact form (using CF7 plugin) using a textarea and a button.

- install contact form 7 plugin
- create a basic contact form
- setting the mailing list (more than 100 mails addresses in Bcc field)

The point here is that the coordinator will write mail and it'll send the mail to the entire mailing list set in the additional headers of Contact Form 7 plugin settings.

I need to test if the mail has been received by everyone.

Another requirement is that i want to be able to send pictures and i need to have a correct text editor.

is there a way to test to send one mail to more than 100 emails adresses without being limited ?
how can i create a large amount of emails addresses for testing ? is there a tool for this ?

In the end, is this the right way to go? Or is there a simpler way to share and update the email list?

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Ars_n

Wordpress: Version 4.9.11

Contact Form 7: Version 5.1.4

Comment: A bit off topic, but depending how often you need to send the emails, the free MailChimp plan would probably be a better idea than putting 100+ email addresses into a WordPress plugin: https://mailchimp.com/pricing/ ... Regarding your original question, why do you need to do a test, can't you use the actual list of email addresses you want to send to? A test using different email addresses won't tell you whether the people you intend to receive it will actually receive it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience mailchimp has been super easy to use and very powerful. It seems like it would be able to solve all your problems you mentioned.

Here is the website: https://mailchimp.com/

Here is a plugin for your wordpress site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/